# set JAVA_OPTS in run.bat of jboss

Tags: java, jboss

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx512m -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -server
```

This argument works in run.bat of jboss but as i want to increase stack size i have added 
-Xss512m
but it's not working.

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xss512m -Xmx512m -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -server
```

What is wrong in it ?

Comment: "it's not working" - based on what do you say that?

Comment: holy cow Xss512m! how about Xss512k ? or Xss2048k. It's the stack size allocated for each thread!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-Xss512m` option increases the size of **every thread stack** to 512 Mbytes.  That's crazy.  I expect that this is *causing* JBoss to run out of memory.

Why are you increasing the stack size in the first place?  The default stack size should be fine for most purposes.  If it isn't big enough then there's a good chance that either:

- you have a bug in your program that is causing **infinite** recursion (and increasing the stack size won't help) or ...
- you are using an algorithm that has a pathological case (and increasing the stack size is a bandaid).

---

Based on your comments, I'd guess that you are using a regex to parse an entire input document containing multiple records.  The regex engine uses recursion to deal with repeating elements / groups.

Assuming that this is the problem, then the fix is to rewrite your parsing code.

Comment: I am facing this error when trying to upload customer in bulk on my system.System work fine for 300 customer but throw exception if i am trying to upload customer around 1000.If there is infinite loop then system did not work for 300 also. Correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Each thread in the VM get's a stack. The stack size will limit the number of threads that you can have, too big of a stack size and you will run out of memory as each thread is allocated more memory than it needs. [source](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/performance/jvm-tuning.xtp)

Clearly `-Xss512m` is too big. Try smaller values, much smaller: `-Xss2048k`